# Remove fake Facebook fans using iMacros?

Tags: facebook, imacros

Our NPO's Facebook page has a lot of fake fans brought in by the previous admin. I'd like to get rid of them so we can actually get some engagement from our real fans. The fake fans all liked our page at the same time andI can bring up a page on Facebook that has a ton of them in a row like so

```
https://www.facebook.com/browse/?type=page_fans&page_id=[MY PAGE ID]&start=800
```

But on that page are non traditional drop-down menus with autogenerated ids. The only option there I can see is to record a mouse position macro to click the menu then 'Remove from Page Likes' then 'Confirm' and repeat. This is slow and after about 30 it goes out of alignment and clicks thin air.

I had a look at iMacros to do things faster but after recording the macro then running it:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#u_0_d" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#u_0_b>DIV>UL>LI:nth-of-type(2)>A>SPAN>SPAN" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#u_o_1>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>BUTTON" KEY=13`
```

Leads to an error:

```
RuntimeError: 
Can not locate element specified by selector "#u_o_1>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>BUTTON", 
line 6 (Error code: -921)
```

I'm assuming that it's because an id has changed between the person I removed when recording and the next person the script is trying to run on. However I'm not sure what I have to change to make it just click or press Enter on whatever button is there on the screen

Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using 'iMacros' for Firefox, try to record your actions in 'Experimental event recording mode'. (Click the 'Record options' button on the 'Rec' tab.)

Comment: @Shugar I was using the Chrome one but I've moved to Firefox and it records what I'm doing! :D Thank you! However I've come across another problem, I'll update my question.

Comment: (1) I suggest recording a removal of several persons so you can catch the dependence between elements. (2) Perhaps it would be helpful to record the last click in another recording mode. (You may simply switch between them during recording.)